# Problems installing docker on 16.04: "Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine."

Tags: 16.04, docker

Just tried to install docker on my Ubuntu 16.04, and I get the error below. Any suggestions what is wrong and how to fix it?

```
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "start" failed.
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-07-28 12:39:11 CEST; 9ms ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 15533 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 15533 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 28 12:39:11 jonas-X555LAB systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Jul 28 12:39:11 jonas-X555LAB systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 28 12:39:11 jonas-X555LAB systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
dpkg: error processing package docker-ce (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu19) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 docker-ce
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I followed this guide: 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-16-04

```
$ curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-cache policy docker-ce
docker-ce:
  Installed: 17.06.0~ce-0~ubuntu
  Candidate: 17.06.0~ce-0~ubuntu
  Version table:
 *** 17.06.0~ce-0~ubuntu 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial/stable amd64 Packages
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial/edge amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     17.05.0~ce-0~ubuntu-xenial 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial/edge amd64 Packages
     17.04.0~ce-0~ubuntu-xenial 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial/edge amd64 Packages
     17.03.2~ce-0~ubuntu-xenial 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial/stable amd64 Packages
     17.03.1~ce-0~ubuntu-xenial 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial/stable amd64 Packages
     17.03.0~ce-0~ubuntu-xenial 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial/stable amd64 Packages

$ sudo apt-get install -y docker-ce
```

On this same machine, I have a Linux Mint 17.3 installation on which docker worked just fine. Using same home directory as before on LM17.3.

Here are some specs:

```
$ inxi -fs
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i3-4005U (-HT-MCP-) cache: 3072 KB 
           clock speeds: max: 1600 MHz 1: 799 MHz 2: 799 MHz 3: 799 MHz 4: 799 MHz
           CPU Flags: abm acpi aes aperfmperf apic arat arch_perfmon avx avx2 bmi1 bmi2 bts clflush cmov
           constant_tsc cx16 cx8 de ds_cpl dtes64 dtherm dts epb ept erms est f16c flexpriority fma fpu fsgsbase
           fxsr ht invpcid lahf_lm lm mca mce mmx monitor movbe msr mtrr nonstop_tsc nopl nx pae pat pbe pcid
           pclmulqdq pdcm pdpe1gb pebs pge pln pni popcnt pse pse36 pts rdrand rdtscp rep_good sdbg sep smep ss
           sse sse2 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 syscall tm tm2 tpr_shadow tsc tsc_adjust tsc_deadline_timer vme vmx vnmi
           vpid xsave xsaveopt xtopology xtpr
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 40.5C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: 2800
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works now. It appears that docker-ce was installed all along and that it failed because I tried to install it again. Very odd. Normally, if you try to install a package that is already installed, you get something like this:

```
$ sudo apt install mypackage
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
mypackage is already the newest version (5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 27 not upgraded.
```

Perhaps the problem was that I had added different repos to /etc/apt/sources.list based on the different tutorials I followed. Embarrassing that I hadn't noticed that the service was running in the background all along and working just fine .. :/

Answer (score 4):

Hi you might want to use `journalctl` to see exactly what is going wrong.

Use it like this:

```
# journalctl -u docker.service
```

To view logs and see what exactly went wrong.

**Tip**: use the `--since` flag to filter your search.

For more information on `journalctl` see [this page](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-journalctl-to-view-and-manipulate-systemd-logs#filtering-by-message-interest).

Comment: Thanks, this seems to have no effect. Btw, this is an Ubuntu 16.04 desktop install with standard Unity DE. And it's a completely fresh install.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [this link](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/22371#issuecomment-215254534) I used the following steps

- wipe /var/lib/docker (rm -rf /var/lib/docker) **this will remove all existing containers and images**.
- edit /etc/default/docker file and add the option:
  DOCKER_OPTS="-s overlay"

then

```
systemctl restart docker.service
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I get this error.

> `Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

Finally, I fixed the error in the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` by adding a missing comma before `registry-mirrors`

```
{
    "runtimes": {
        "nvidia": {
            "path": "/usr/bin/nvidia-container-runtime",
            "runtimeArgs": []
        }
    }    

    # I forget to add a comma , here !!!!!!!
    "registry-mirrors": ["https://docker.mirrors.ustc.edu.cn"]
}
```

After I added the comma and restarted docker with `systemctl restart docker`, I solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I could fix my problem with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57648759/8358986) solution.
For me, the problem was using the VPN connection which changes the gateway address. When I disconnect my VPN connection it got fixed. Remember to run 
`sudo systemctl start docker` after disconnecting your VPN connection

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes